# new line needed in text file by using blob

Tags: javascript, object, text, blob

I have a ***data*** variable which is an object

> data = ["Madhav mishra", "keshav mishra"]
> I am saving this data as a plain text using blob

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
    }),
```

I want my text file with every value of data in new line, like this

[image]

But I am getting my text file as

[image]

I tried using this but it's not working. Help me please thanks.

> data.replace(/([^\r])\n/g, "$1\r\n");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using join for that for appending the breakline for each element in the array

```js
const data  = ["Madhav mishra", "keshav mishra"];
let newFile = new Blob([data.join(',\n')], {type: "text/plain", endings: 'native'});

newFile.text().then(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: I tried using your code but the text file is just separated with commas like this "Madhav mishra,Keshav mishra" without new line. I forget to mention one thing that I am trying to download the text file as well using js, so maybe that collide with your code, my downloading code looks like this, tell me if any thing need to be change. My code is below this comment

Comment: let textFile = new Blob([data.join(',\n')], {type: "text/plain"}),
        e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a = document.createElement('a')
        
    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFile)
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)   @Ran Turner

Comment: Try to change:
    {type: "text/plain"}
to    
    {type: "text/plain", endings: 'native'}